# Problem with Spring Data JPA @Query Annotation (error in SQL syntax)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

**EDIT:** I want to check if a certain user has a privilege in a group. If there is a better solution without querying all his privileges please tell me.

The following query gives me one error I couldn't understand:

```
@Repository
public interface PrivilegeRepository extends JpaRepository<Privilege, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Privilege p " +
            "inner join p.userTypes " +
            "inner join UserGroup u " +
            "where u.user.id=:uid and u.group.id=:gid")
    List<Privilege> getPrivilegesOfUser(@Param("uid") Long uid, @Param("gid") Long gid);

}
```

error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where usergroup1_.user_id=28 and usergroup1_.group_id=18' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

UserGroup entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_to_group")
public class UserGroup {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @MapsId("groupId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id")
    private UserType userType;

    @Column(name = "is_blocked",
    insertable = false)
    private boolean isBlocked = false;
```

I tried first the equivalent query in the MYSQL Workbench and worked just fine. Nothing with Jpa repository implementation.
This is the code that works on MYSQL:

```
select p.name from privilege p 
    inner join user_type_to_privilege utp 
        on p.id=utp.privilege_id
    natural join user_to_group utg
    where utg.user_id=16 and
        utg.group_id=9;
```

This is the dialect I use: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
Is this outdated or something?

Comment: Your JPQL query parses and compiles to an invalid MySQL query, which it shouldn't. Turn on logging of `org.hibernate.SQL` to `trace` level to get the generated query and file a bug report at [Hibernate's JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH). If it's an invalid JPQL query (for maybe not having explicit join criteria), then it should fail before reaching the database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on the second inner join. It was ambiguous and didn't know which column to match for the join.
Query that works:

```
@Query("select p from Privilege p " +
            "inner join p.userTypes t " +
            "inner join UserGroup u on t.id=u.userType.id "+
            "where u.user.id=:uid and u.group.id=:gid")
    List<Privilege> getPrivilegesOfUser(@Param("uid") Long uid, @Param("gid") Long gid);
```